# Pegar registros de 3 tabelas com JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, join

Preciso pegar dados de 3 tabelas no mesmo SELECT. Preciso apenas pegar os dados do usuário da tabela **usuarios**, pegar a quantidade de cotas (coluna quantidade_cotas) que o usuário tem da tabela **cotas** (se tiver registro nessa tabela do usuário) e a quantidade de faturas que o usuário tem na tabela **faturas** (se tiver também). Tentei fazer assim:

```
SELECT u.login, SUM( c.quantidade ) AS qtd , SUM( COALESCE( f.status, 1, 0 ) ) AS qtdF
FROM usuarios AS u
LEFT JOIN cotas AS c ON c.id_user = u.id
LEFT JOIN faturas AS f ON f.id_user = u.id
```

Mas ele me retorna o dobro de quantidade nas colunas **qtd** e **qtdF**.

Era pra ele me retornar tipo:

> alissonacioli | 14 | 2

E ele está me retornando

> alissonacioli | 28 | 4

Não sei se tem que usar `subquery` nesse caso, e se tiver não sei como fazer, mas estou com um problemasso ;/

Comment: O que você está tentando com esse `COALESCE( f.status, 1, 0 )`? E "cotas" é o que? Uma quantidade de cotas que varia por registro?

Comment: Na verdade seria só `COALESCE(f.status, 0)`, pq se for `NULL` ele deixa como 0. `cotas` é uma tabela aonde tem uma coluna chamada **quantidade_cotas** que tem valores que variam e se tiver registros dos usuários, então ele deve somar cada coluna **quantidade_cotas** daquele usuário. Fiz um comando MySQL agora aqui que funcionou do jeito que queria. Vou postar aqui, se puder analisar e tiver uma saida boa :)

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente só falta o GROUP BY:

```
SELECT u.login, SUM( c.quantidade ) AS qtd, SUM( f.status ) AS qtdF
FROM usuarios AS u
LEFT JOIN cotas AS c ON c.id_user = u.id
LEFT JOIN faturas AS f ON f.id_user = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
```

Quanto ao COALESCE, seria interessante você explicar o que quer, pois não faz muito sentido como está, e como você não explicou o formato dos dados de `f.status`, é meio complicado deduzir.

O que você pode, é usar algum tipo de condicional, por exemplo:

```
SUM( IF( f.status IS NULL, 1, 0 ) )
```

ou o inverso.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolvido**

Resolvi essa minha questão fazendo o comando:

```
SELECT u.nome, (
SELECT COALESCE(SUM( c.quantidade ), 0) AS qtd
FROM cotas AS c
WHERE c.id_user = u.id
AND c.status =1
) AS quantidade_cotas, (
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(IF(f.id, 1, 0)),0) AS qtdF FROM faturas AS f
WHERE f.id_user = u.id
) AS quantidade_faturas
FROM usuarios AS u
```